Spectrum of a Satisfiable Sentence
Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a first order language including only the equality sign $\approx$. Let $A$ be an arbitrary sentence in $\mathcal{L}$ and define its spectrum as follows
$$\text{Spec} A = \{\text{Card} |\mathfrak{M}|: \, \mathfrak{M} \vDash A, \, \text{Card} |\mathfrak{M}| < \aleph_0\}.$$
For every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $\lambda_n$ be a sentence saying that "There is at least $n$ objects" (This is a very famous sentence so I didn't write down its equivalent in $\mathcal{L}$). If $B$ is a satisfiable sentence constructed from $\{\neg, \wedge, \lor \}$ and $\lambda_i$, then show that
\begin{align}
\text{Spec} B &= \bigcup_{i=1}^n I_i, \\
I_i &= \{m\in \mathbb{N}: \, m \ge a_i\} \quad \text{or} \quad I_i =\{m\in\mathbb{N}: \, a_i \leq m \leq b_i\},
\end{align}
for some $a_i, b_i \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Here is a closely related question. But it's not a duplicate, because you are asking about the "easy part" that tomasz's answer takes for granted (when he writes "It follows that any sentence is equivalent to a Boolean combination of these predicates, which yields the proposition", your question is asking how exactly this yields the proposition).

Hint: Try to define the set of sentences like $B$ inductively. Then use structural induction on that set to prove the desired property for spectrum of sentences in this set.

Seems like you've solved your own problem. I'm glad to hear it! Sorry I didn't get around to writing an answer. You can accept your own answer so the question is marked as resolved.

@AlexKruckman: Thanks Alex. Your hint on the other related question also helped to figure this out.
